# Google Goals process not working through similarly named pages

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, goals

Well, I'm at a loss.

I've ensured that my tracking script is in  etc etc, and I've set up my goal and funnel path, but only the first step is ever being shown on the funnel.

Goal URL: `/checkout/checkoutComplete/`
Type: **Head Match** ... but should this be `/checkout/checkoutComplete/(.*)` and set to regex  rather because there are parameters after the main part of the URL (I thought that's what head match was for)

Step 1: `/checkout/`  <-- required

Step 2: `/checkout/confirm/`

both the above are valid and correct URLs for my domain.

But for some reason, the funnel visualization shows entries into the first step, then an exits count that matches the entry count, including `/checkout/confirm` - but it doesn't go on to the next step!

Perhaps I'm doing something obviously wrong...but I can't quite see it?

Also, semi-related questions. Making a change to the funnel, does it only affect new incoming data? And how often does it update?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using the Regular Expressions option was the answer. I also removed the trailing slashes at the end of the steps. That seems to have solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Change it to regex. You require /checkout/confirm/, but say that /checkout/confirm is also a page - this wouldn't be matched with Head Match.

Regarding the last question: yes, only new data will be processed with the changes.